# python bubble sort that stops when the list is sorted

Tags: python, bubble-sort

hi i am studing python and i tried to make a bubble sort algorithm that stops when it realizes the list is sorted for an excersise can someone tell me if this is correct

```
def bubblesort(list):
    done=False
    n=len(list)
    if done==False:
        for i in range(0, n-1, 1):
            for j in range(n-1, 0, -1):
                if list[j]<list[j-1]:
                    list[j],list[j-1]=list[j-1],list[j]
                else:
                    done=True
```

Comment: Do you want us to test your algorithm for you? Just test it. If you need a reference here it is: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/bubblesort

Comment: i have tested but i am not sure that it does less swaps

Comment: I don't think it is right. Irrespective of the `done` flag, both the `for` loop executes till the end. You can simply use counter to count how many time it executed for sorted list. My suggestion is to use `while` loop instead of `for` for the top most loop where you can check `index` and `flag for done` both.

Comment: @openSource is this right  while i<len(list)-1 and done==False

Comment: I think you can let `i` go till `<len(list)` and yes `done == False` or you can use `not done` as well. And don't forget to initialize `i` before and increase `i` after done with all `j` i.e. `for` loop for `j`. I strongly recommend checking with counter, so that you can understand what was going on before and after you make change.

Comment: @openSource ok thanks for your help

Comment: For your reference you can also check at https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html , look for method named `shortBubbleSort` which is same thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I made this one a while ago using a similar technique, I think your use of logical operators may have cause the problem (Note where my program uses > or < as opposed to ==).

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
bubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)
```